# How to set Delivery order state to 'done' with XMLRPC Odoo 9

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I want to set delivery order state to `done` from PHP via xmlrpc, so I'm trying it like this,

```
$write = $client->write('stock.picking', array(23), ["state" =>"done"]);
```

Using this method works to set any other parameter, but it does not set state to `done`

Can you see what I'm doing wrong here or what is the proper way to set it `done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allow to write **state** field in **stock.picking** , because **state** field is **calculative store field** in **stock.picking** model **odoo**.

You must update **state field** of stock.move, odoo will automatically change state of stock.picking.

You can follow below odoo code.

**picking.move_lines.write({'state':'done'})**

This may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but how can I do this via XMLRPC?

Comment: I think you need pass stock move & stock move ids. $write = $client->write('stock.move', array(24,25), ["state" =>"done"]);  you will get stock move ids from stock picking ex: picking.move_lines.ids